# DLL Injection crashes the target depending on the compiler and system used

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, dll, code-injection

Well, this is a weird one.
When the injector is compiled with an older version of Delphi (I think it was 2009, but I can't be sure - I found the app with my old "toys") it works flawlessly both on Windows 7 (64-bit) and Windows 8 (64-bit).

However, when compiled with XE5, the same code works on Win7 but **does not** work on Windows 8 - it causes an Access Violation on execution, and I can't find a proper reason for it.

Do keep in mind that the injector, target, and dll are all 32-bit PE files.

I need to use the new compiler, as I don't have the old Delphi version anymore and this piece of code is supposed to be a part of a bigger application that uses some of Delphi's new features.

On a side note - the dll needs to be injected, so that I can log certain things in the target. For now all I'm injecting is a stub that simply shows a messagebox, so it can't be the DLL's fault.

This is the code I'm using to inject the DLL:

```
function InjectDLL(PID: Cardinal; sDll: String): Boolean;
var
  hLib: Pointer;
  hThread: THandle;
  pMod: Pointer;
  hOpen: NativeUInt;
  dWritten: NativeUInt;
  ThreadID: Cardinal;
begin
  Result := False;
  hOpen := OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, False, PID);
  if hOpen <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
  begin
    hLib := GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(PChar('KERNEL32.dll')), PWideChar('LoadLibraryW'));
    pMod := VirtualAllocEx(hOpen, nil, (Length(sDll) + 1) * SizeOf(char), MEM_COMMIT or MEM_RESERVE,
      PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
    if WriteProcessMemory(hOpen, pMod, @sDll[1], (Length(sDll)) * SizeOf(char), dWritten) then
      Result := TRUE;
    hThread := CreateRemoteThread(hOpen, nil, 0, hLib, pMod, 0, ThreadID);
    WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(hOpen);
    CloseHandle(hThread);
  end;
end;
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated, I think I'm starting to get crazy because of this...

Edit:
If you want to run the test yourself, here's a sample injector, a dll, and a target - all ready to compile:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15031178/Stack%20Overflow/Test%20inject.rar

Comment: `sDll` appears to be a multi-byte string - you're only copying `Length(sDll) * SizeOf(char)` bytes, and yet you're using `LoadLibraryW` which expects a Unicode string.

Comment: I've tried with simple AnsiStrings yet the problem still persists. Using OllyDbg I can see that the sDll is being written to the memory correctly, the target app seems to crash once CreateRemoteThread is called. Unless I use the version compiled with the earlier version of Delphi that is, exactly the same code seems to work then (I've kept the sources...) :f

Comment: I think you missed my point - with an ANSI/multibyte string, you should use `LoadLibraryA`, not `LoadLibraryW`.

Comment: @Jonathan, in XE5 (and 2009, for that matter), `string` is `UnicodeString`, so this code's use of `LoadLibraryW` is appropriate. Length*SizeOf(Char) is exactly right.

Comment: Is the target string properly null-terminated? In C/C++ you would want `(strlen(sDll) + 1) * sizeof(char)` so that the null is copied as well (note that this *is* used when allocating the memory, so it looks inconsistent either way).

Comment: How about changing the stub code to something simpler like OutputDebugString()? Maybe it has to do with the message box that you display.

Comment: The second argument to `GetProcAddress` is always an ANSI string, so using `PWideChar` looks wrong.  Perhaps Delphi is doing some translation though.

Comment: @HarryJohnston There's a `GetProcAddress` defined in the RTL Windows unit that converts `LPCWSTR` proc name to `LPCSTR`, for the benefit of code like this.

Comment: @PickledPorpoise Can you please supply complete SSCCE. So that we can reproduce the fault. Because I cannot reproduce it with this code. The code is messy, with poor error handling and misleading variable names. But it does inject just fine. Until you can supply an SSCCE, there is no question here.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan My point is that exactly this code **works** on Windows 8 if compiled with an older version of Delphi but doesn't if compiled with XE5. Both cases work on Windows 7.  

- PeterK The dll injects just fine if the injector was compiled with an older version of Delphi, so I doubt it's the issue. I have tried your suggestion though and nothing changed, the target still crashes.

Oh, and also - the injection crashes all targets not just one specific app...

Comment: So let's have an sscce then so we can repro the issue. I won't do more until we have one.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan
Edited the original post with a link. There is an injector, a dll and a sample target included. As with the original issue, the target crashes on win8 after injection and the messagebox is **not** displayed.

Comment: I'm not going to down load something external. Code should be in the question. There's not very much needed.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan
I don't quite get what you need then. The contents of the DLL don't matter, it crashes anyway. The target doesn't matter either, even an empty VCL app crashes. The injection code is included in the question. As I said, it only crashes if the OS is windows 8 and the injector was compiled in XE5, if it was compiled with the earlier version of Delphi it's fine.

Comment: Try to change protection mode to PAGE_READWRITE.